# Using Realm how a pod inside a my framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, realm, cocoapods

I need to implement some system to save the data. I want to use Realm, but I will not be a good option to use as a pod within my framework.

I'm implementing a framework that captures GPS coordinates and sends it to a server. That framework will be used by other apps.

Will there be some issues if using Realm (Objective C ) as a pod within my framework? Or it will be issues free?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why there would be issues with using Realm as a CocoaPod. Try adding Realm to your project using CocoaPods [by following these instructions](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation). If you have any issues with this, please follow-up and we can help you from there.

Comment: If I transform my framework in workspace with pods it will include libPods.a in my Linked Frameworks of my Framework and that will be considered a nested framework (a lib, but also is a binary so I think the problem is the same) and apple don't allows nested frameworks (framework inside a framework).  And if I have Realm inside my app and inside my Framework I think will have conflicts.